# Iteratively append new data into pandas dataframe column and join with another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have been doing data extract from many API. I would like to add a common column among all APIs.
And I have tried below

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1,200): 
  url = '{id}/values'.format(id=i)
  res = request.get(url,headers=headers)
  if res.status_code==200:
     data =json.loads(res.content.decode('utf-8')) 
     if data['success']: 
        df['id'] = i 
        test = pd.json_normalize(data[parent][child])
        df = df.append(test,index=False)
```

But data-frame id column I'm getting only the last iterated id only. And in case of APIs has many rows I'm getting invalid data.

Comment: In your last line:  df = df.append(test, index=False), shouldn't 'index=False' be 'ignore_index=False'?  That's the standard argument for df.append().

Comment: Sorry code update df = df.append(test, ignore_index=True). Indexing is not problem here only appened dataframe column iteratively.

Comment: What are you trying to do with df['id'] = i ? You are repeatedly putting i value in the id column

Comment: @gtomer iteratively i would like to append values to df['id'] . Ex : loop is range from 1..10. df['id'] values would be 1...10

Comment: Try without the line: df['id'] = i . I don't see why you need it

Comment: if this does not help, please add the url and headers so  I can test your code

Answer (score 0):

From performance reasons it would be better first storing data in a dictionary and then create from this dictionary dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(1,200):
  # simulate dataframe retrieved from pd.json_normalize() call
  row = pd.DataFrame({'id': [i], 'field1': [f'f1-{i}'], 'field2': [f'f2-{i}'], 'field3': [f'f3-{i}']})
  for k, v in row.to_dict().items():
    d[k].append(v[0])

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```